# How do I convert ushorts to strings?

Tags: c#

The following code works just fine.  At the end, variable keyFileName correctly contains "K1_1". But there must be a better way of getting the string.

```
ushort us1 = 0x4B31;
ushort us2 = 0x2E31;
string keyFileName = "";
keyFileName = Convert.ToString((char)(us1 >> 8)) + 
              Convert.ToString((char)(us1 & 0xFF)) + 
              Convert.ToString((char)(us2 >> 8)) + 
              Convert.ToString((char)(us2 & 0xFF));
```

Isn't there a better way than this?

Comment: Looks fine to me... There is unlikely significantly better way to convert 2 ushort to a string... you may want to clarify what exactly you are looking to improve in this quite reasonably looking code. Would be so much easier if you just read it as byte array of 4 bytes...

Answer (score 1):

We can use `BitConverter.GetBytes()` to get the bytes of the `ushort` values. The problem is that the endianness is opposite to what we need for converting to a string.

While we can still achieve the conversion, **I think your original solution is more elegant.** For the sake of providing it, here is the solution I came up with:

```
ushort us1 = 0x4B31;
ushort us2 = 0x2E31;
string keyFileName = "";
byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(us1).Reverse()
                .Concat(BitConverter.GetBytes(us2).Reverse())
                .ToArray();
keyFileName = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
```

Of course, instead of reversing the bytes for the individual shorts, we can join the whole thing together in reverse order and then reverse the entire resultant byte collection. This should make it a little bit easier to read this part:

```
byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(us2)
                .Concat(BitConverter.GetBytes(us1))
                .Reverse()
                .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution but I am not sure that if it is a better way for you

This is the converter struct:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct YourConverter{
    [FieldOffset(0)] public byte byte1;
    [FieldOffset(1)] public byte byte2;
    [FieldOffset(2)] public byte byte3;
    [FieldOffset(3)] public byte byte4;
    [FieldOffset(0)] public uint value;
}
```

This is the main code:

```
YourConverter yc = new YourConverter();
yc.value = 0x4B312E31;
string keyFileName = "" + (char)yc.byte4 + (char)yc.byte3 + (char)yc.byte2 + (char)yc.byte1;
```

You can change the converter struct if you have to work with `ushort`. Therefore, you should remove 2 of bytes.

By the way, I see the output as **K1.1**

Comment: Yes, it's K1.1.